# Converter C++ para C#

Tags: c#, c, c++

Bom, estou passando uns códigos do qual tenho, e estou dúvida para conseguir passar tal código para c#, e queria a ajuda de quem puder ajudar, no seguinte código abaixo

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

bool extracoes();

int main()
{
    bool saida;
    //"Interface"
    saida = extracoes();
    if(saida)
        std::cout<<"Copias concluidas!!!\n\nPressione qualquer tecla para encerrar!";
    else
        std::cout<<"Erro! Executar instalacao como Suporte\n\nPressione qualquer tecla para encerrar...";
    std::cin.get();
}

bool extracoes()
{
    struct dirent *lsdir;
    DIR *dir;
    int qtd=0, i=0;
    bool padrao;
    std::string path;
    dir = opendir("D:\\Users\\");

    while((lsdir = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        qtd++;

    std::string users[qtd];
    closedir(dir);

    dir=opendir("D:\\Users\\");
    while((lsdir = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        padrao=true;
        std::string aux = lsdir->d_name;
        if(aux.size() == 7)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
            {
                if(!(aux[j]<=57 && aux[j]>=48))
                {
                    padrao=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            padrao=false;

        if(padrao)
        {
            users[i]=aux;
            i++;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);

    users[i]    = "Default";
    users[i+1]  = "\0";
    i           = 0;
    padrao      = true;

    //Config Global
    if(system("Xcopy kds_kodak c:\\ProgramData\\kds_kodak /v /e /y /h > nul") == 0)
        std::cout<<"Extracao Config_Globais concluida\n\n";
    else
    {
        padrao = false;
        std::cout<<"Erro na extracao Config_Globais\n";
    }
    //Config default e usuários
    while(users[i].compare("\0"))
    {
        std::cout<<"Copiando...\n";
        path = "Xcopy \"Smart Touch\" \"d:\\Users\\";
        path += users[i]+"\\AppData\\Local\\Smart Touch\\\" /v /e /y /h > nul";

        if(system(path.c_str()) == 0)
            std::cout<<"Copia do usuario "<<users[i]<<" concluida!!\n\n";
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Copia do usuario "<<users[i]<<" nao concluida!!\n\n";
            padrao = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return padrao;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Você quer um código equivalente em C# ou você quer uma ferramenta que faça essa conversão pra você?

Comment: se possível um código equivalente, pois este aplicativo faz a copia de uma pasta de arquivos procurando todos os usuários que tem num usuário com 7 dígitos que seriam a matricula, porem feito tudo em prompt. Mas se em c# desse para fazer de outro método que fizesse a copia de tal pasta colocada na raiz do executável para tal determinado lugar assim como está no código serviria também

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é um pedido de código pronto.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal nem seria responder, visto que uma tradução de código de uma linguagem pra outra pode ser feita com o uso de uma ferramenta como esta:

https://www.varycode.com/

Entretanto, vou colocar na resposta algumas diretivas úteis na hora de converter seu código.

### 1. Crie um Console Application

Isto que você tem é uma aplicação console. Comece criando um projeto no Visual Studio como **Console Application**.

### 2. Entrada e saída

```
cout << "Olá, Mundo";
```

Pode ser substituído por

```
Console.WriteLine("Olá, Mundo");
```

E também:

```
cin.get();
```

Pode ser substituído por:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

### 3. Comandos da Shell

Para executar um comando da Shell, use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "Xcopy kds_kodak c:\\ProgramData\\kds_kodak /v /e /y /h > nul");
```

## Demais códigos

Tendo essas linhas base, basta adaptá-las para a lógica que você precisa.

Comment: Teria alguns exemplos de programas bons para conversão, e no caso estava querendo tirar o mesmo do console application se possivel e passar para windows form

Comment: Coloquei um link de uma ferramenta gratuita. [A Tangible também tem uma ferramenta paga](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html). Para converter sua aplicação para Web Forms, não existe ferramenta. Terá que ser na verdade uma reimplementação do seu sistema antigo.

Comment: @SNOT, pra salvar a pergunta, em vez de pedir *"escreve código aí pra mim"*, você pode deixar ela mais genérica e adequada a esta grande resposta, algo do tipo *"Diretrizes na hora de converter C++ para C#"*.